# Replacing Substring in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have situation in Java where I am reading contents of file in String. It is something like this -

```
String S = "<name>source</name> <value>NB_System</value> </nameValue> <nameValue> <name>timestamp</name> <value>2015-6-25 22:39:41:455</value> </nameValue> <nameValue> <name>TTL</name> <value>0</value> </nameValue>"
```

I want to delete the timestamp from the string - `timestamp</name> <value>2015-6-25 22:39:41:455</value>`

Timestamp is creating issues in comparing results with master copy. How to get rid of timestamp here?

Comment: ... parse, find indexes and then call `String.substring(...)`? What code have you tried?

Comment: Your text looks like XML. Why don't you use XML parser and remove nodes or their content you don't want? Also [regex is not best tool to parse XML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/1393766).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the tag timestamp with its value, you can use a code like this:

```
S = S.replaceAll("<name>timestamp.*?<\/value>", "");
```

On the other hand, if you just want to get rid of the value tag for the timestamp you could use:

```
S = S.replaceAll("<name>timestamp.*?<\/value>", "<name>timestamp</name>");
```

Comment: Corrected : S = S.replaceAll("<name>timestamp.*?</value>", "");

Answer (score 0):

```
S = S.replaceAll("<name>timestamp</name>[^<]*<value>[^<]*</value>", "");
```